# c# ASP.NET Bundle & add cache break query string inside css url properties

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, caching

I am trying to develop an automated way of breaking the cache on files linked via css url properties, in an ASP.NET C# application that uses [Bundles](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).

Specifically, I have recently added an icon font to my website, the css that creates the @fontface loads the font files by url:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "iconfont";
  src:url("/fonts/iconfont.eot");
  src:url("/fonts/iconfont.eot&#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/fonts/iconfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/fonts/iconfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/fonts/iconfont.svg#iconfont") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This means the font file is cached by the user the first time they load the page. But I need to break this cache if I update the font files, I can achieve this using a query string such as:

```
src:url("/fonts/iconfont.eot?v1");
```

However, I would like to be able to achieve this through code so that I don't have to maintain query strings on all css properties that use url in my site.

My bundle code looks like this so far:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/IconFont").Include("~/css/iconFont.css"));
```